# Is it possible in TypeScript for an object to behave differently depending on its generic type?

Tags: arrays, typescript

My intention is to extend the `Array` prototype with the following methods:

- `clone()`, returns a deep copy of the array and its `Clonable` objects
- `contains(object: Equatable)`, returns `true` if the corresponding `Equatable` object is found, `false` otherwise.

```js
interface Clonable<T> {
  clone(): T
}

interface Equatable<T> {
  contains(object: T): boolean
}
```

What I've tried with type conditionals is:

```js
interface Array<T extends Clonable<T>> {
  clone(): Array<T>
}

interface Array<T extends Equatable<T>> {
  contains(object: T): boolean
}
```

And I would expect this to have the following meaning: "if the `Array`'s generic type extends `Clonable<T>`, then the `clone()` method will be available and if its generic type extends `Equatable<T>` the `contains()` method will be available under the assumption that `Array<T extends ...>` represents a conditional. I'm also aware that at runtime both `contains()` and `clone()` will be available on `Array` regardless of its generic type.

This, however, throws an error:

```js
const myArr: Array<number> = new Array<number>(); // Type 'number' does not satisfy the constraint 'Equatable<number>'.ts(2344)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Generics only exist at compile-time. You can't really have run-time variation based on compile-time knowledge. 2. `T` is supposed to be a assignable to `Equitable<T>`. And `Equitable` has to have a `contains()` method. `number` does *not* have a `contains()` method, it cannot be assigned to `Equitable`.

Comment: Hey VLAZ, I appreciate the comment. 1. I'm aware that when extending the `Array` prototype both `clone()` and `contains()` will be available at runtime regardless of the generic type; my question is about... TypeScript, so compile-time knowledge exclusively. I'll update the question. 2. What do you mean "`T` is supposed to be assignable to `Equatable<T>`"?

Comment: 1. You're asking if it's possible to vary the implementation based on generics. No, it's not because the implementation is executed at run-time, TS only exists at compile-time. You cannot have different behaviour for `method<T>(x)` and `method<U>(x)`. Unless you also add some sort of run-time check for what `x` is (assuming that's what the generic determines). There is no real way to know what generic something was executed with. Assuming a signature of `method<T>(x: any) : T` you'd be unable to vary the output if you've called `method<string>` or `method<number>`.

Comment: As for 2. you have `T extends Equatable<T>` which means that `T` is a subtype of `Equitable<T>`. Thus any `T` must also be a valid `Equitable<T>`. With `Array<number>` this would not and *cannot* compile because `number` is not a valid `Equitable<number>`. It's not an `Equitable` because the primitive does not have a `contains()` method.

Comment: 1. I'll have to update the question again and make it clearer - my intention was not to ask whether it's possible to vary the implementation, rather whether it's possible for TypeScript, at compile-time, to discern `Array<Clonable>` from `Array<Equatable>` or any other type that is not `Clonable | Equatable` to render available, depending on the declared `Array` generic, either `clone()` or `contains()`. I know at runtime there will be no distinction whatsoever.

Comment: 2. Woah! Generics operate over aggregation? I've used `Equatable<T>` to allow `contains()` to return the correct type! And in fact `Array<T extends Equatable>` seems to work fine - this might very well be another SO question, but how would I thus go about allowing `contains()` to return the `Array`'s generic type?

Comment: I'd flip things around and just make very simple functions that consume `Equitable`/`Clonable` arrays. No real need to change native objects. https://tsplay.dev/WoqbPN There is probably a better signature for these functions but not sure how to type it precisely.